# Android getselectionStart and Getselectionend text don't work

Tags: android, textview, getselection

could anyone explain, what i'm doing wrong?

in this case below, "tt" is my TexView.
On my Oncreate() method, I have:

```
tt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ni);
tt.setText("This is a try");
```

and then

```
tt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String vi = tt.getText().toString().substring(tt.getSelectionStart(),tt.getSelectionEnd());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), vi,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

        });
```

Nothing is Shown at Onclick.

thanks.

Comment: It looks like you're missing a little code - should be more like setOnClickListener(...) ?  Anyway, try breaking the action down into a few more statement so it's easier to debug.  Put start and stop into local variables.  One more thing: you will get multiple onClicks - how do you know which one is the result of highlighting the selection?  Instead of Toast, use the log file - easy way: System.out.println ("...stuff...");

Comment: Thank you, @PeriHartman. I guess my problem is with the methods to getselection, because if I replace the methods for numbers, my toast works fine, shown the substring.

Answer (score -1):

I encountered the same problem a few days ago and I could find the following solution in the end. Delaying the process even 10 milliseconds could help interestingly. Put this in your onClick/onLongClick method, wherever you want to fetch the selected text.

For the original answer: [textView.getSelectionEnd() returning start index value on Samsung Marshmallow 6.0 devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37429711/textview-getselectionend-returning-start-index-value-on-samsung-marshmallow-6)

I hope this helps those who have similar problem in the future.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                int startIndex = textView.getSelectionStart();
                int endIndex = textView.getSelectionEnd();

                if ((endIndex - startIndex) <= 0) {
                    return;
                }

                // UI related code here
            }
        }, TIME_IN_MS_TO_DELAY);
        return false;
```